# Grouping and Filtering rows in reportviewer rdlc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, expression, reportviewer, rdlc

I currently have a report viewer page - rdlc and displaying information from a dataset. My dataset returns information like:

Meeting - 3 hours 5 cases
Visit - 2 hours   2 cases

---

Organization - 5 hours
Prepare - 3 hours

I want to display in a table a totals row for all the activities that have 'case' and the second row will be the total for all activities WITHOUT 'cases.

Like so:
Totals with cases: 5 hours 7 cases
Totals without cases: 8 hours

Is there a way that i can display this information by entering a specific expression to filter based on the number of cases?

I tried this for an expression for the cell i want to show the number of hours that don't have a case but will always get the totals for both case and without case.

```
=IIf(Fields!Cases.Value is Nothing, Sum(Fields!Hours.Value), Nothing)
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the work around. I created a table with a single row and for that row i entered the following expression for the GoupOn:

```
=IIf(Fields!Cases.Value is Nothing," " ,Fields!OfficeName.Value)
```

and in the first column i wrote an expression to see if it was case or non case based on the number of cases. The table when ran produced two rows one for case and the other for non-case with proper information in each.